ModelMapper does not mapping boolean null value
I am trying to convert model to entity class. Here is my modelmapper object
private ModelMapper getMapper(){
    ModelMapper ob = new ModelMapper();
    ob.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    ob.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
    return ob;
};

Now I requirement is to convert Resource to ResourceEntify where boolean fields are there.
List<Properties> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(Properties.builder().key("key").uuid("uuid").valueBoolean(false).build());
    arrayList.add(Properties.builder().key("key 3").uuid("uuid 32").valueString("string value").build());
    Resource resource = Resource.builder()
            .name("name")
            .owner("owner")
            .source("source")
            .properties(arrayList)
            .build();

Here is my Resource class.
ResourceEntity entity = getMapper().map(resource, ResourceEntity.class);

after converting I got property with boolean value false for both property where first property has null value.
null convert into false.
Any Idea to solve it. or its a bug in model mapper ?
